# Where can I find the openoffice fonts not in Libre like calibri

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

OPenoffice has several nice fonts that are not part of the standard Libre install. Where / how can they be obtained for use in Libre or do I need to install OpenOffice on my ubunut 16.10 to be able to use them?
I understand OpenOffice is being depreciated, but on this point at least so far, it seems to have an advantage.

Interestingly, I have noticed that in Libre if I edit a text.odt which uses fonts like Calibri which is not available in Libre it will conintue to use and preserve the "alien" font. However, if I cut and paste text that is in a libre font such as Ariel, I can not get it into the alien font.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104701) for a discussion on the subject and for alternatives that can be used by LibreOffice.

[Comment #6](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104701#c6) has this:

> the non Unicode Type 1 PS fonts have been completely dropped with ESC approval

Some links to sources mentioned there:
 - http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/
 - http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=urw-core35-fonts.git;a=tree
 - http://practicaltypography.com/charter.html

Answer (score 0):

Calibri is a font from Microsoft and it is not a free open-source font.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibri

You can find the font here.
https://www.downloadfonts.io/download/calibri-font/