# Fonts in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

This is driving me crazy! When I type Activities, search for fonts, a whole bunch show up. They are all installed according to the button at the top of the window. But most of them are not showing up in LibreOffice? A few of the fonts (not showing up in LibreOffice) are in /usr/share/fonts/XII/type 1. The font manager says there are 139 system wide fonts installed. /local/share/fonts is empty. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-fonts-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux did not answer my question. I am brand new at this, so please keep it simple. I guess the root question is how do I get all the apparently installed fonts into LibreOffice? I have Ubuntu Bionic Beaver distribution. There is no cache. LibreOffice 6.0.7.3. Oh, if I open a document created in a font not in LibreOffice (say Schoolbook), the document will open in Schoolbook in LibreOffice? I would guess there is a very simple solution; thanks for taking the time to answer. (Please spell out your answer in great detail.)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023694/where-can-i-find-the-openoffice-fonts-not-in-libre-like-calibri/1023697#1023697

Answer (score 0):

Since the `fonts` through `activities` appear to you just fine, it seems like it is a problem of permissions. Check that the full path to your fonts is accessible to the groups and it is not only accessible by sudo rights (File/Folder rights -> http://www.macinstruct.com/node/415 ).

Long shot try opening Libre with sudo, and if the problem persists, try copying all the fonts onto the local font folder, which should be under the path `~/.local/share/fonts`.